# How to save selected radio button value in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a assessment model like Rails Survey Gem (runtimerevolution), there teacher create a MCQ assessment for student. Its Options are in type of radio button. there one option is correct.

when a student apply for a MCQ assessment, it get a question paper where Question has multiple options and student select one option through radio button.

So I just want to store that selected option_id regarding question_id in my new model attempt.

Here is apply page of MCQ for student.

```
<div class="stream-cont">
    <%= form_tag(action: "apply") do %>
        <% @mcq.questions.each_with_index do |q, i| %>
            <div class="feed-cont-title all-header">
                <p>
                    <%="Question-#{i+1}: "+ q.question %>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <strong>Answer : </strong>
                    <%=
                      collection_radio_buttons("questions[#{q.id}]", :option_id, q.options, :id, :option) do |b|
                        b.label(style: "display:block") { b.radio_button + b.text }
                      end
                  %>
                </p>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= submit_tag "Submit Answer", :class => "typeD button" %>
</div>
```

here is Mcq controller

```
    def apply

            @club = current_user.clubs
            if current_user.user_type == User::User_types[:student]
                @mcq = Mcq.find(params[:id])
            end

            @attempt = current_user.attempts.new

            @mcq = Mcq.find(params[:id])
            @attempt = current_user.attempts.new(attempt_params)
            @attempt.save
            redirect_to attempt_id(@attempt.id), notice: "Thank you"
        end

        Private
        def attempt_params
          params.require(:attempt).permit(:user_id, :mcq_id,    :question_id, :option_id)
       end
    end
```

it is not complete and I know it is incorrect. I just want to know how I get selected Option_id regarding question_id and save this value in attempt model's option_id column.

I have know idea how to manage it and what should use in view and controller.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, why do you have an `apply` method?

---

Rails relies heavily on the [`CRUD`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) infrastructure; your request *should* go into an `applications` controller, tied to an `Application` model:

```
#app/models/application.rb
class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
    #columns id | mcq_id | user_id | created_at | updated_at
    belongs_to :mcq
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :answers, class: "ApplicationAnswer"
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
end

#app/models/application_answer.rb
class ApplicationAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
    #columns id | application_id | question_id | answer_id | created_at | updated_at
    belongs_to :application
    belongs_to :question
    belongs_to :answer
end

#app/models/mcq.rb
class MCQ < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :applications
    has_many :questions
    has_many :answers, through: :questions
end

#app/models/question.rb
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | mcq_id | etc | etc
   belongs_to :mcq
   has_many :answers
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers #-> you can make a nested form; each time you make a question, you can make answers
end

#app/models/answer.rb
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    #columns id | question_id | value | created_at
    belongs_to :question
end
```

Looks complicated; all it does is split up your data as follows:

> 1. `MCQ` (collection of questions & possible answers)
> 2. `Applications` (user provides details such as why wanting to join etc)
> 3. `ApplicationAnswers` (user's answers to questions. Separate model to provide extensibility (IE can add as many answers per question)
> 4. `Questions` (tied to MCQ; provides ability to add a question & assign answers to it).

--

This means that you can do the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :mcqs, only [:show] do
   resources :applications, only: [:new, :create] #-> url.com/mcq/:id/applications/new
end

#app/controllers/applications_controller.rb
class ApplicationsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @mcq = MCQ.find params[:id]
   end
   def create
      @mcq = MCQ.find params[:id]
      @application = @mcq.applications.new application_params
      if @application.save
         # ...
      else
         # ...
      end
   end

   private

   def application_params
      params.require(:application).permit(:application, :params, :mcq_id, answer_params: [:question_id, :application_id, :answer_id]).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
   end
end
```

Now, the form you're looking to create has the ability to save `ApplicationAnswers` *through* your `Application`:

```
#app/views/applications/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @mcq.applications.new do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :your_mcq_stuff_here %>
   <%= f.fields_for :answers, @mcq.questions do |question| %>
      <%= question.hidden_field :question_id, question.id %>
      <%= question.collection_radio_buttons :answer_id, question.answers.all, :id, :value %>
   <%= f.submit %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Several issues here include the [`n+1`](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/n_plus_one/) query issue, and the fact I've not tested it.

--

If this works properly, you'll basically be able to give `users` the ability to submit an `Application` to an `MCQ`. Each `MCQ` will have a series of `Questions`, those questions having a series of `Answers`.

This will probably need tweaking; it's the structure I'd use for this type of project.

Comment: Yes, I use this approach for creating Mcq and its done successfully. At the student phase I want to catch selected option_id and store it in attempt model. So that I perform check operation for student result.

Comment: Which is exactly what I've described. Sorry my code is not cut-and-paste, you'll have to work out how to do it yourself.

Comment: I'm using `<%= question.collection_radio_buttons :question, que.options, :id, :option %>` It pass `"attempt"=>{"attempt_options_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"question"=>"31", "id"=>"15"}, "1"=>{"question"=>"33", "id"=>"16"}, "2"=>{"question"=>"35", "id"=>"17"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Attempt"}` but `Unpermitted parameters: question, id`.... I want store **question** value in column option_id of Attemptoption model ....

Answer (score 0):

The Mcq is actually the top level model here, not Attempt, so I think the nesting is causing a bit of confusion.

You can leverage form_for and fields_for in this situation, which will nest the params hash for you.  It would look something like this:

```
<%= form_for @mcq do  |f| %>
    <% f.fields_for :question |question_fields, i| %>
        <div class="feed-cont-title all-header">
            <p>
                <%="Question-#{i+1}: "+ question_fields.object %>
            </p>
            <p>
                <strong>Answer : </strong>
                   <% question_fields.fields_for :option |option_fields| %>
                       <%= option_fields.radio_button(:id) %>
                       <%= option_fields.label(:name) %>
                  <% end %>
            </p>
        </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You then want your controller to whitelist the params like:

```
Private
    def mcq_params
      params.require(:mcq).permit(:user_id, :mcq_id,  questions_attributes[ :id, :options_attributes[:id]])
   end
```

When you submit the form, your params will look something like

```
:mcq[:user_id, :id, questions_attributes[][:id, :options_attributes[:id]]
```

At that point, you just iterate through the questions attributes hash to build the attempts objects on the user.

Sorry if the code is not spot on - I am not sure I completely understand the relationship between question and options, but this should get you headed down the path.  If it is too nesty, you can keep the radio buttons collection, I just find that over time, forms tend to get complicated so it's kind of nice to have rails nest them for you.

Comment: Similar approach I used but I get error - 'param is missing or the value is empty: attempt' In line         'params.require(:attempt).permit(:user_id, :mcq_id,  questions_attributes[ :id, :option_id])'

Comment: Probably has to do with the way that option_id is being nested in the questions attributes.  if you nest them completely as above, you will only have :id columns for both questions and options.